# c# How to get the original object of list element Not references

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have two classes: `ClassA` and `Test`

1. I want to set `Test.classA = null` by `ClassA.Clean()`.
2. I dont want use `Test.classA` directly

The code:

```cs
public class ClassA 
{
    private static List < ClassA > list = new List < ClassA > ();
    public ClassA() 
    {
        list.Add(this);
    }
    public static void Clean() 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
        {
            //var classA = list[i];
            //classA = null;
        }
    }
}
public class Test 
{
    private static ClassA classA;
    void DoSomething() 
    {
        if (classA == null)
            classA = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok man:
1. Sorry for bad english :D  - writes litelary 2 basic sentences^^ (no hate)

2. So you have a class test which contains an object of classA...and you want to "clear" classA

I dont know a way to "clear" an object, but you can clear the list in classA whitch list.clear().

Btw i dont realy understand what you are trying to do....you have a classA with a list and you fill this list with the same object of classA and this object contains a list which contains classA which contains a list........ you get the point...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one more class for List of ClassA, or example

```
public class ListClassA
{
  public list;
  public ClassA()
  {
    list = new List<ClassA>();
  }
  public void Clean()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    { 
       list.Clear();
    }
  }
}
public class ClassA
{
   private static ListClassA list = new ListClassA();
   public ClassA()
   {
     list.Add(this);
   }
   public static void Clean()
   {
     list.Clear();
   }
}
```

OR

you need [collections.generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8), because is has [Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Clear) function.